# Inotify monitor sub-directories with certain depth?

Tags: linux, inotify

Is it possible to monitor files in newly created sub-directories up to a certain level with inotify?

Let's say that there is a structure:

```
/home/user1/data
/home/user2/data
...
```

New users are added regularly.

We want to monitor only data inside "data" directory, but don't want to monitor data in newly create sub-directories, for example if user creates "/home/user3/data/test_uploads", it shouldn't be processed.

If we use inotifywait with the following syntax, it will check only existing directories:

```
inotifywait -m -e close_write /home/*/data/
```

If we create new user in /home, it won't be processed because inotify scans existing directories only.

Is there any way to monitor newly added directories up to a certain level, but not use `"-r"` option as it will monitor all sub-directories?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What system is adding users? What system is adding files to the data directories? [There may be a better way to solve your problem than the solution you're asking for help implementing.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inotifywait` has `--exclude` option, but unfortunately it doesn't have `--include` option and it doesn't support extended POSIX regular expressions, so it's not possible to include only files *not matching* given pattern. See details in [this answer](/a/38288561).

Other options:

- You can just `grep` output of `inotifywait`, but this way you can't avoid the overhead for monitoring all unnecessary child files.
- You can use patched `inotifywait` with `--include` option, as described in answer linked above.
- You can write your own program using `inotify` API directly, so that you can control what files to monitor and what to exclude. There are bindings for various scripting languages too, including Python.
- You can use various `inotify` wrappers, e.g. [`watchdog`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) module for Python.

---

Here is an example using `watchdog` Python module with [`watchdemo.py`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/blob/master/src/watchdog/watchmedo.py) script from their repo.

Start monitor:

```
$ python2 watchdemo.py shell-command \
    --recursive \
    --pattern='/home/*/data/*' \
    --ignore-pattern='/home/*/data/*/*' \
    --ignore-directories \
    --command='echo "${watch_event_type} ${watch_src_path}"' \
    /home
```

Create files and directories:

```
$ mkdir -p /home/user/data
$ touch /home/user/foo
$ touch /home/user/data/bar
$ mkdir /home/user/data/baz
$ touch /home/user/data/baz/qux
```

The monitor output will be:

```
created /home/user/data/bar
modified /home/user/data/bar
```

Note that `/home/user/foo` and `/home/user/data/baz/qux` were not matched.

If you need to filter events by type:

- If you're using `watchdemo.py`, check type in the shell command:

  ```
  ... \
  --command='[ "${watch_event_type}" = created ] && echo "${watch_src_path}"'
  ```
- If you're using `watchdog` Python module directly, derive custom event handler from [`FileSystemEventHandler`](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler) and overwrite required methods, e.g. `on_created`.

Comment: Thanks for this, really useful! There are two questions for this approach:

1) Is it possible to somehow monitor only "created" event, without "modified"? The goal is to be notified only once if file is created

2) If I put full path for --pattern='/home/*/data/*' instead of --pattern='./*/data/*', it doesn't work, not sure why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for 1), see updated answer. for 2), try `--directory` option of watchdemo with an absolute path

Comment: Thanks! First option is working brilliant, it is displaying "created" events. However second one with directories doesn't work, I tried with --directory and it doesn't recognize the flag, looks like it doesn't exist. I tried with option "directories /home/user" but there is an error "OSError: Path is not a directory". Looks like something is wrong with directory directive

Comment: @Igor My mistake. Directories are passed to `watchdemo` as positional arguments, without option. See updated answer.

Comment: Hi @gavv, Looks like there is a problem with this approach because file is reported as "created" before file is actually closed. As a consequence, it is processing files which are actually not completely written. Is there any way to process file only after it's completely written and closed?

Comment: @Igor, You probably want `close_write` event. I didn't test it.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "close_write" event. It is displaying only "Created file" and "Modified", but the problem is that "Created file" is reported at the beginning only and not on the closing system call.

Comment: @Igor, this event is probably hidden by `watchdog` module. Probably not. You could ask on their github.